# D3JS V5.5 - CSV FireFox Request not using cookies

Tags: firefox, d3.js, jenkins, cookies

We are running a Jenkins server with several reports. The reporting format is with D3JS and HTML. The Jenkins requires an Authentication with User/PW, once done, it uses cookies. This was working all right with D3JS V4.

However recently I wanted to upgrade to D3JS V5 and now for some reason when the script is about the parse the CSV, the request does not contain the Cookies in the headers in FireFox. In Chrome it's working properly, with V4 it's working properly, in those cases the JS Fetch sends the cookie, and recieves the CSV file without a problem. However with V5 no cookie is sent in FireFox, thus the server responds with 403.

My FireFox version is 52.9.0 (32 bit), and everyone is using this forefox version at the company with the same missing cookie for everyone.

Comment: Related: [*"Why doesn't d3.json send cookies with the request?"*](/q/50725520).

Comment: Thank you! With this lead I found out that the FF with versions 39-60 are using outdated fetch settings, and I have to set the `credentials` to `same-origin` manually.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the suggestion of @altocumulus I found the solution. I had to change my CSV part
from this:

```
d3.csv("data.csv",  buildDataBase).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data).......
```

to this:

```
d3.csv("data.csv", {credentials: 'same-origin'}, buildDataBase).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data).......
```